Ordering users by "rank counts" column with or without ORDER BY in MySQL
I have a game and it have 10 worlds and each world have 20 levels.
and have a ranks table like this:



id
user_id
world_num
level_num
rank




#
userId1
1
1
3


#
userId1
1
2
1


#
userId1
5
15
12


#
userId1
2
5
2


#
userId2
1
1
1


#
userId2
1
2
2


#
userId2
5
15
4


#
userId2
2
5
1


...







so user_id,world_num,level_num group is uniq (each user only have one "world_num = 1,level_num = 1" row and rank)
and i have a rank column it shows the rank for world_num,level_num group. (For every levels i ranked the list with code.)
I want to show a "Overall Ranking list screen", its will show Global Top rank users.
I want to write a sql code for:
The user with the most "rank 1" should be top of the list,
if two users have same "rank 1" count than the user with the most "rank 2" should be the second
and so on...
I write a sql code like this:
SELECT `user_id`, `rank`, COUNT(`rank`) AS 'rank_count'
FROM score
GROUP BY `rank`

when i run this i have ranks and rank counts but i couldn't order like:
ORDER BY 'rank_count_1', 'rank_count_2', 'rank_count_3', 'rank_count_4' ....

A table i want to show is like that:
1. userId92 (rank1Count = 60)
2. userId45 (rank1Count = 57, rank2Count = 46, rank5Count = 8)
3. userId12 (rank1Count = 57, rank2Count = 40, rank3Count = 17)
4. userId76 (rank1Count = 55, rank3Count = 20, rank4Count = 80)
5. userId33 (rank1Count = 55, rank4Count = 25, rank5Count = 35)
...

How can i write a sql for "Overall Ranking list"?
column user_id here is exactly what i want: https://dbfiddle.uk/-YLilhd4

Can't we just sum and ordering like this https://dbfiddle.uk/-YLilhd4 ?

@MarsPeople Its is unclear what result you want. Please show the expected outcome as correct table, not as a list of text. Do you want one column only with a whole string that contains all the rank data? I would not recommend this. Or do you want a solution like User12345 proposed? I think this would be much better.  Add NULLIF to their solution if you want ranks that don't occur to be NULL rather than zero: ...NULLIF(SUM(user_rank  = 1),0).... The result you currently show in your question makes the impression the number of columns should differ depending on the data. That's impossible.

@User12345 your link result table exactly what i want! but your created the "rank1Count", "rank2Count" ... columns one by one but it can be infinite. as i understand i can't do this with just sql query... i should write a sql to get a result table as i wrote above then i have to order the users list with PHP array etc as i understand :/

@Jonas Metzler thanks for answer, but as i wrote to "User12345" the "user_id" column in result table in here: https://dbfiddle.uk/-YLilhd4 is exactly what i want. but i can't write the "rank1Count", "rank2Count", "rank3Count"... one by one. As i understand i have to create columns for "rankXCount" and then i should use ORDER BY rank1Count DESC, rank2Count ... but it is impossible as i understand. I have to do this with PHP code after i get a usefull sql result table as i understand.

For this, you can use dynamic sql to achieve that. Here is the sample code
SET @sql = CONCAT('
    SELECT user_id, ', (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                'MAX(CASE WHEN user_rank = ', user_rank,
                ' THEN rankCount ELSE 0 END) AS rank', user_rank, 'Count'
            )
            ORDER BY user_rank
        )
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT user_rank FROM score
        ) AS subquery
    ), '
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, user_rank, COUNT(*) AS rankCount
        FROM score
        GROUP BY user_id, user_rank
    ) AS counts
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY ', (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('rank', user_rank, 'Count DESC') ORDER BY user_rank)
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT user_rank FROM score
        ) AS subquery
    )
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Here is the sample dbfiddle to test it out. But, it may just rank based on available rank. As you can see, it will be rank 1,2,3,4,12 and no rank 5,6,...,11 because can't found in sample data.

It seems a bit tiring code, but the result is correct. I solved the question with PHP loop generated SQL code using SUM(user_rank  = 1) and ORDER BY. But this sql looks good i will check thanks.
